# How do I get the Line Ending styles and Line Dash pattern using Pdfium library?

Tags: pdf, line-endings, pdfium

I would like to take the **Line Ending** styles (like Open, Round, Butt etc.) and **Line Dash** pattern (like an array [4 3 4 3]) using the Pdfium library.

If anyone knows the API or any other way to retrieve this information, please share your suggestions here.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: what do you mean "get" them?